# Sampling without replacement, final input

Tags: combinatorics, algebra-precalculus

I'm studying probability and I'm stuck on counting. When sampling without replacement the definition is $n(n - 1)···(n-k+ 1)$ possibilities. Why is there a "$+1$" for the final step? If you can explain using examples that would be tremendously helpful, I haven't reached the stage where I can solely rely on intuition.

Comment: $\underbrace{n(n-1)(n-2)(n-3)}_{\text{four terms}}$, notice that $n-3$ is the fourth term in the sequence $n,n-1,n-2,n-3$.  Similarly, the $k$'th term in the sequence $n,n-1,n-2,n-3,\dots$ will be $n-k+1$

Answer (score 1):

First term $n-0$.

Second term $n-1$

third term $n-2$.

$k$-th term: $n-(k-1)$ term.

The thing is we started counting from $0$ rather than $1$.